# Why I see these two folders in /media?

Tags: 20.04, mount, hard-drive, home-directory

I just followed this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) to move my `/home` folder to a new drive.

All went OK, but I got this doubt/question:

- As far as I know, the `/media` folder it's where removal media devices appear. Now, and I believe that this is since I've moved the `/home` folder to the new drive, I see two folders there: one named `home` and the other `my username`.

At first I though it was normal since my `/home` folder is now on a second hard drive, and because of that it's mounted then appears in `/media`.

But then things get weird for me:

- Those two folders are empty, and if I check properties they have the size of my `/root` hard drive, so they are not mounted drives since they belong to `/root` (right?).

So my thought is: These are some "leftovers" from the moving process and it's OK for me to delete them, but then, is it really OK for me to deleted them?

Why do I see these to folders here and what are they?

Comment: I think in the end, something did get wrong with your move. Check if and where /home is mounted in the output of the command "mount | grep home".

Comment: It's on the right place as far I can understand - "mount | grep home shows me /dev/nvme1n1p1 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime). I reckon the nvme1n1p1 as the right SSD.

Answer (score 2):

You created the folder `/media/home` during the move operation, as a temporary location on where to mount the destination partition for your home. Now, it is an empty mountpoint and can be safely deleted.

The folder `/media/your_username` is a folder created by the Ubuntu system. Removable drives that are plugged by a user are automatically mounted in an automatically created folder under `/media/your_username`, and deleted when the drive is unmounted. Leave that folder there.

Comment: Remove with `rmdir`, and you'll be safe, as this will only remove empty directories.